# How can I pass an array list on ngModel?

Tags: arrays, angular, forms, ngmodel

I'm reworking this project , with Angular now, before i was using getlist inside a form tag  , how can I get this form input array (prod[], qtd[]) to put on ngModel and send to my backend?

```
<div>
<div class="row justify-content-around col-md-12">
<select class="form-control col-md-5 produtos" name="prod[]">
<option value="1">TST-01 - </option>
<option value="2">TST-02 - </option>
<option value="3">TST-02 - Teste-02</option>
</select>
<div class="col-md-7">
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
<input class="form-control col-md-2 mt-1 quantidade" min="0" max="999" type="number" name="qtd[]" placeholder=" Qtd">
<br>
</div>
```

ngModel:

```
produto = { produto_desc: '', codigo: "", tipo: "", valoruni: "", valoruniDol: "", quantidade: 0, qtdvalorTot: 0, Compvalortot: '', CompvalortotDol: '', prod: [], qtd: [] };
```